# How to capture an error from the library python litex.Regon?

Tags: python, exception, lib

I want Handling Exceptions from litex Regon (polish library with information about company). I don't know how? When i try with

When i try with this code it's ok... so i don't know why?

```
while True:
    try:
            x = int(input("Please enter a number: "))
            break
    except ValueError:
            print("Oops!  That was no valid number.  Try again...")
```

But my code is doesn't work

```py
## EXAMPLE
api = REGONAPI('https://wyszukiwarkaregon.stat.gov.pl/wsBIR/UslugaBIRzewnPubl.svc')
USER_KEY = 'my_key'
api.login(USER_KEY)
entities = api.search(nip='9222976976')
c = etree.tostring(entities[0], pretty_print=True)
c

## MY CODE
REGONAPI('https://wyszukiwarkaregon.stat.gov.pl/wsBIR/UslugaBIRzewnPubl.svc')
USER_KEY = 'my_key'
api.login(USER_KEY)
from litex.regon import REGONAPI
lista = []
for i in np.arange(280, 300):
        try:
            entities = api.search(nip=dane_do_przeszukwania['NIP'][i])
            c = etree.tostring(entities[0], pretty_print=True)
            lista.append(c)
        except REGONAPIError:
            None
```

I have a error

```
EGONAPIError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-7-f2653b5824bc> in <module>
      4         try:
----> 5             entities = api.search(nip=dane_do_przeszukwania['NIP'][i])
      6             c = etree.tostring(entities[0], pretty_print=True)

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\litex\regon\__init__.py in search(self, nip, regon, krs, nips, regons, krss, detailed)
    210         if not result:
--> 211             raise REGONAPIError('Search failed.')
    212 

REGONAPIError: Search failed.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-7-f2653b5824bc> in <module>
      6             c = etree.tostring(entities[0], pretty_print=True)
      7             lista.append(c)
----> 8         except REGONAPIError:
      9             None
     10 

NameError: name 'REGONAPIError' is not defined
```

if I do not find it number hand error and next row in iterate.

Answer (score 0):

`REGONAPIError` is not defined because you probably didn't import it.
Try adding

```py
from litex.regon import REGONAPIError
```

in your file, this should work.

Comment: I import this library :)

Comment: Did you import it as in my answer above or as `import litex.regon.REGONAPIError`? You then have to write `except litex.regon.REGONAPIError:` instead.

Comment: Oh sory - i was reading "import REGONAPI", no "import REGONAPIError". Yes i import "from litex.regon import REGONAPIError" .

except REGONAPIError is work :)

Answer (score 0):

```
from zeep import Client, Settings, xsd
from lxml import etree
from litex.regon import REGONAPI

nip_number = '9999999999'
pKluczUzytkownika = 'yourkey'

api = REGONAPI('https://wyszukiwarkaregon.stat.gov.pl/wsBIR/UslugaBIRzewnPubl.svc')
login_response = api.login(pKluczUzytkownika)

# Use the session identifier in subsequent requests
sid_header = {"sid": login_response}    

# Call the DaneSzukajPodmioty method
dane_response = api.search(nip=nip_number)

# Print the XML content in a formatted string
for elem in dane_response:
   print(etree.tostring(elem, pretty_print=True).decode("utf-8"))


bartek@Vostro:~/mycode/invoice_rec$ python bir.py
<dane>
  <Regon>524708207</Regon>
  <Nip>5833473245</Nip>
  <StatusNip/>
  <Nazwa>GOLDEX SP&#211;&#321;KA Z OGRANICZON&#260; ODPOWIEDZIALNO&#346;CI&#260;</Nazwa>
  <Wojewodztwo>POMORSKIE</Wojewodztwo>
  <Powiat>Gda&#324;sk</Powiat>
  <Gmina>Gda&#324;sk</Gmina>
  <Miejscowosc>Gda&#324;sk</Miejscowosc>
  <KodPocztowy>80-890</KodPocztowy>
  <Ulica>ul. Jana Heweliusza</Ulica>
  <NrNieruchomosci>11</NrNieruchomosci>
  <NrLokalu>811</NrLokalu>
  <Typ>P</Typ>
  <SilosID>6</SilosID>
  <DataZakonczeniaDzialalnosci/>
  <MiejscowoscPoczty>Gda&#324;sk</MiejscowoscPoczty>
</dane>
```